# Auxiliary routes not showing component

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I am trying to implement auxiliary routing in my angular app, but for some reason the component is not shown, even though that the url in the browser changes.

My routes module looks like that:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'students', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: StudentsComponent, outlet: 'main' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: HomeComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

The `HTML` template of the `HomeComponent` essentially boils down to:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<div class="">
    <button [routerLink]="[{outlets: {main: ['students'] } }]">aux route</button>

<!-- <button [routerLink]="[{outlets: {main: ['/students'] } }]">aux route</button>
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '%2Fevents' -->

    <router-outlet name="main"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

So, basically when I open `http://localhost:4200` in the browser, I can see my aux button and when I click it, the url in the browser changes to: `http://localhost:4200/(main:students)`

It looks fine, but the `StudentComponent` is never shown on the page.

I wonder what I do wrong...

The `StudentComponent` just displays the default:

```
<p>StudentComponent works!</p>
```

**EDIT**: I am adding a link to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c8e8du) that shows the problem. Please notice how the content of the third component is never shown.

Comment: can you reproduce a minimal example of this problem in stackblitz

Comment: @RahulSingh Sorry about the late reply, please checkout this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c8e8du The content of the third component is not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [**modified version**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-roobzz) of your stackblitz, which appears to work with these routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'first', component: FirstComponent },
  {
    path: 'second', component: SecondComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'third',
        component: ThirdComponent,
        outlet: 'third'
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

and the following template for the second component:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { third: ['third'] } }]">Aux third component</a>

<router-outlet name="third"></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Thank you. A minor difference in the definition of the routes, but a significant outcome.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to salvage a example for you on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/auxiliary-routes). hope it helps

**App Routing**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import ComponentOne from './component-one';
import ComponentTwo from './component-two';
import ComponentAux from './component-aux';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'component-one', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'component-one', component: ComponentOne },
  { path: 'component-two', component: ComponentTwo },
  { path: 'component-aux', 
    component: ComponentAux, 
    outlet: 'sidebar'
  }
];


export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

**App Component Template**

```
<nav>
    <a [routerLink]="['/component-one']">Component One</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/component-two']">Component Two</a>
    <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { 'sidebar': ['component-aux'] } }]">Component Aux</a>
</nav>
<div style="color: green; margin-top: 1rem;">Outlet:</div>
<div style="border: 2px solid green; padding: 1rem;">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<div style="color: green; margin-top: 1rem;">Sidebar Outlet:</div>
<div style="border: 2px solid blue; padding: 1rem;">
    <router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. Could you please checkout the one I added as well. I cannot see why it doesn't display the content of the aux component.